# How to force case-sensitive auto complete in XCode (7.2)

Tags: macos, xcode

It looks like there used to be a way to do this:
[Older Article](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.19/19.11/XcodeandCodeCompletion/index.html)

However, now it appears to be missing from the preference screens. Am I missing it? If not, is there a way to do more advanced preferences manually?

Would love to control this to give me quick typing speed without thinking I used the wrong case when I started a word.

Comment: [FuzzyAutocompletePlugin](https://github.com/FuzzyAutocomplete/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin)

Comment: So this would be like if you had two variables `horse` and `Horse` that it would complete based on the case you used?

Comment: [beta release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3_beta_4/Xcode_7.3_beta_4_Release_Notes.pdf) on pg 21 says that Code Completion has been improved and has mention of capitalization, but I don't use Xcode so..

Comment: Right now if I type something like "horse", even with the lower "h", I get in my top completion result "House" or something... and the completion even will show as though I typed in a capital H until in this example I got to an 'r'

Comment: @rahul_send89 Looked through that but I do not see that it handles my issue... see my last reply. Is that covered?

Comment: @RiddlerDev : I am currently using FuzzyAutocompletePlugin and autocompletion is working fine for me . you & also you have option updated the plugin yourself . just try it .
Its the closest you can get in Xcode . not actually what you want. AppCode have that option though .